# viewflow.io: Is there a way to have 'subflows'?

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

With the ViewFlow library (see http://viewflow.io/), is it possible to have dynamic 'subflows'?

The use case:

I have a static process for checking out a basket of products in a webshop.
The first step in the process is to look into the basket and gather input form the user: For each item in the basket, I have a specific process (and a specific flow) for gathering information from the user to customize the item. When all the information for the respective items in the basket is gathered, the MAIN process should continue to the next step.

The idea is that the respective processes/flows for all of the items in the basket are reusable in different 'main' processes.

I could not find any documentation on how I can achieve such architecture with ViewFlow. Can anyone help me on my way?

Comment: There is a `DynamicSplitActivation` node in `demo/customnode/nodes.py` in the [viewflow source code](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/customnode/nodes.py). It should be approximately the kind of thing you need.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research.

It's called **subprocess**, a smaller unit which can be rolled back individually. I think this is what you want. Works with subprocesses each having its own Flow class and is included in the main flow
You can find [example](https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/4e1df5fc0327383302efd92715cd7298b51a36d4/subprocess) on GitHub (provided by the developer).

News: Subprocess is only included in the PRO version of viewflow.